# iText cann't convert HTML with link of google drive file

Tags: java, itext

I used iText to convert HTML to PDF and write PDF to my Google Drive. My code works good. 
But when I used HTML with link for file in my Google Drive, iText generates a PDF file without file link! As it's shown in this picture:

[image: generated pdf]

It should be looks like : (when I open the html string in chrome):

[image]

Anyone knows why iText doesn't convert Google Drive files links? Or where exactly is the problem.

My code:

```
// my html string 
String htmlBody = "<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <div dir="ltr">
   hallo&nbsp;
   <div>
    <br />
   </div>
   <div>
    here is my doc :
   </div>
   <div>
    ​<br />
    <div class="gmail_chip gmail_drive_chip" style="width:396px;height:18px;max-height:18px;background-color:#f5f5f5;padding:5px;color:#222;font-family:arial;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:1">
    <a  href="https://docs.google.com/a/sotec.eu/document/d/1OEuQP2VdfonswF_TgyfRjzg2gBtFeP2b4tGrlYSMMUA/edit?usp=drive_web" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;padding:1px 0px;border:none;width:100%">
    <img style="vertical-align: bottom; border: none;" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_document_list.png" />&nbsp;
        <span dir="ltr" style="color:#15c;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:bottom">test doc</span>
     </a>
    </div>​
   </div>
   <div>
    salam
   </div>
  </div> 
  <br /> 
 </body>
</html>";

// convert html to pdf using iText:
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfStream);
document.open();

CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new MySpecialImageProviderAwareHtmlPipelineContext();
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
htmlContext.setImageProvider(new MyImageProvider());

PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlBody.getBytes("UTF-8")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

document.close();

[// use the iText output to create pdf in my google drive:

File fileData = new File();
fileData.setName("my pdf file");
fileData.setId(newFileId);
fileData.setMimeType("application/pdf");

AbstractInputStreamContent in =  new ByteArrayContent(fileData.getMimeType(), pdfStream.toByteArray());

File file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileData, in).execute();][1]
```

Comment: What happens when you remove all the CSS from your HTML string?

Comment: actually The HTML string is coming from Email. I try to convert email to pdf and save it in my google drive. 
so html string is automatically generated or it is depends on email message.
I write it as string in my question just to avoid writing very long code.
The link with its css generated in email (html email) when I add file from drive in my Email message by using (insert files using drive)  button in gmail.

Comment: The code works good when I remove CSS from my HTML string!!!

Comment: It might be some "special" CSS that XMLWorker cannot handle. You should try with iText 7 and the pdfHtml add-on, it has a lot better CSS support.